# Error while getting data from mysql using HttpClient module of angular 5

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular5

I created a service to get data from and I am stuck at the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: this.http.get(...).map is not a function

[image]

I am using the `HttpClient` Module. Here is my script:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class Api{
    public data: any = [];
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){ }

    getPartnersName(){
        return this.http.get('http://aff.local/getPartners.php', {
      observe: 'response',
      responseType: 'json'
    }).map(
        (data)=>{
          console.log(data)
        },
        error=>{
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I still can't see the data in my component:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.api.getPartnersName().subscribe(
        (data)=>{
          this.data = data;
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: the **default response type in HttpClient is `json`** using `map` is not required if  you want to console.log use `do`

Comment: `HttpClient` implementation already includes inner using of the `map` ... it works for you automatically. refer this link https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20460

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I know the problem. With `HttpClient` you need to import the `map` function and use it with `pipe`. Also remove `responseType` - default is set `json`.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map'
```

In the method

```
return this.http.get('http://aff.local/getPartners.php', {
          observe: 'response'
       }).pipe(
               map(data => { 
                      console.log(data);
                      return data;
               })
       );
```

And just for logging., you can use `do` function instead of `map`.

Comment: Correct by I still can't see the data on my html page

Comment: But do you get the data in your function ?

Comment: See my edit at the end of my question. Solve this and I will vote and chose your answer

Comment: @droidnation ))). Show component template

Comment: It just obvious. We haven't return it. Updated

Comment: Yeah. It works now. But we are returning the full `this.get...`, why I should return inside the response too ?

Comment: Because the `map` gets the response, changes/can it and must return it into the next handler to do to some other work and till to the `subscribe`